# Cannot see controllers in Unity scene/game view

Tags: unity-game-engine, htc-vive

We are experiencing a issue with the HTC Vive Controllers on Unity version 2018.3.7f1. Yesterday we have worked within our Unity project and everything worked. Suddenly, the controllers disappeared in the scene/game view.

I have tested the vive controllers in the Steam VR room and they are working there. However, if I make a new Unity project with either a SteamVR player or a CameraRig, the controllers do not show up.

I want to know, is this a SteamVR bug? And is there a workaround for it?

Could someone give me some insight?

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Did you update any plugins or something between yesterday and today?

Comment: No I did not =[

Answer (score 0):

Do not know exactly how it has been fixed.
I've re-installed unity, steam, steamVR and it suddenly worked.